# Loop over returned table and drop each table with the same name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that returns a table containing every child table of a given parent table.

I want to drop all the child tables and for that I'm trying to loop over the result of the function :

```
Do$$
BEGIN
FOREACH child IN
SELECT partman.show_partitions('public."parent"',p_include_default := TRUE)
LOOP
    DROP TABLE child
END LOOP
END$$;
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the function I'm using it's from the postgresql extension pg_partman :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partman.show_partitions(p_parent_table text, p_order text DEFAULT 'ASC'::text, p_include_default boolean DEFAULT false)
 RETURNS TABLE(partition_schemaname text, partition_tablename text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 STABLE
 SET search_path TO 'partman', 'pg_temp'
AS $function$
DECLARE

v_control               text;
v_control_type          text;
v_datetime_string       text;
v_default_sql           text;
v_epoch                 text;
v_parent_schema         text;
v_parent_tablename      text;
v_partition_interval    text;
v_partition_type        text;
v_sql                   text;

BEGIN
/*
 * Function to list all child partitions in a set in logical order.
 * Default partition is not listed by default since that's the common usage internally
 * If p_include_default is set true, default is always listed first.
 */

IF upper(p_order) NOT IN ('ASC', 'DESC') THEN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT set_config(%L, %L, %L)', 'search_path', v_old_search_path, 'false');
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'p_order paramter must be one of the following values: ASC, DESC';
END IF;

SELECT partition_type
    , partition_interval
    , datetime_string
    , control
    , epoch
INTO v_partition_type
    , v_partition_interval
    , v_datetime_string
    , v_control
    , v_epoch
FROM partman.part_config
WHERE parent_table = p_parent_table;

IF v_partition_type IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Given parent table not managed by pg_partman: %', p_parent_table;
END IF;

SELECT n.nspname, c.relname INTO v_parent_schema, v_parent_tablename
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE n.nspname = split_part(p_parent_table, '.', 1)::name
AND c.relname = split_part(p_parent_table, '.', 2)::name;

IF v_parent_tablename IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Given parent table not found in system catalogs: %', p_parent_table;
END IF;

SELECT general_type INTO v_control_type FROM partman.check_control_type(v_parent_schema, v_parent_tablename, v_control);

RAISE DEBUG 'show_partitions: v_parent_schema: %, v_parent_tablename: %, v_datetime_string: %', v_parent_schema, v_parent_tablename, v_datetime_string;

v_sql := format('SELECT n.nspname::text AS partition_schemaname, c.relname::text AS partition_name FROM
        pg_catalog.pg_inherits h
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = h.inhrelid
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
        WHERE h.inhparent = ''%I.%I''::regclass'
    , v_parent_schema
    , v_parent_tablename);

IF v_partition_type = 'native' AND current_setting('server_version_num')::int >= 110000 THEN

    IF p_include_default THEN
        -- Return the default partition immediately as first item in list
        v_default_sql := v_sql || format('
            AND pg_get_expr(relpartbound, c.oid) = ''DEFAULT''');
        RAISE DEBUG 'show_partitions: v_default_sql: %', v_default_sql;
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_default_sql;
    END IF;

    v_sql := v_sql || format('
        AND pg_get_expr(relpartbound, c.oid) != ''DEFAULT''');

END IF;

IF v_control_type = 'time' OR (v_control_type = 'id' AND v_epoch <> 'none') THEN

    IF v_partition_interval::interval <> '3 months' OR (v_partition_interval::interval = '3 months' AND v_partition_type = 'time-custom') THEN
        v_sql := v_sql || format('
            ORDER BY to_timestamp(substring(c.relname from ((length(c.relname) - position(''p_'' in reverse(c.relname))) + 2) ), %L) %s'
            , v_datetime_string
            , p_order);

    ELSE

        -- For quarterly, to_timestamp() doesn't recognize "Q" in datetime string. 
        -- First order by just the year, then order by the quarter number (should be last character in table name)
        v_sql := v_sql || format('
            ORDER BY to_timestamp(substring(c.relname from ((length(c.relname) - position(''p_'' in reverse(c.relname))) + 2) for 4), ''YYYY'') %s
            , substring(reverse(c.relname) from 1 for 1) %s'
            , p_order
            , p_order);

    END IF;

ELSIF v_control_type = 'id' THEN

    v_sql := v_sql || format('
        ORDER BY substring(c.relname from ((length(c.relname) - position(''p_'' in reverse(c.relname))) + 2) )::bigint %s'
        , p_order);

END IF;

RAISE DEBUG 'show_partitions: v_sql: %', v_sql;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_sql;

END
$function$
;
```

As you can see the function returns a table and I want to loop on each row and drop the the corresponding child table.

Comment: Please post the definition of show_child() function.

Comment: I've edited my post and added the function definition

Comment: I cancelled my answer since you are far from my expectation about how to use fonction in posgresql. There many mistakes, begin to correst the 2 mains : name of the function and foreach, There are at least 2 minors you should find by testing and probably a last major point that we'll see later if need.

Comment: you should use cursor and iterate each row and delete the child table. But in this case, these are all partitions of a table, so you could simply drop the partitions using any function in partman extension.